# Dynamics 365: Extending Staging and TargetEntity with Custom Fields

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations, d3fo

I am trying to Extend the LedgerJournalEntity with new CustomFields

I have added into my project

Solutions Explorer Screenshot:

[image: Solutions Explorer Screenshot]

Mapping Details

[Mapping Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms03n.png)

All the required Artifacts

I have created an Extension project and added three Fields in LedgerJournalEntityStaging and LedgerJournalTrans
I have also regenerated Mapping from TargetEntity Form. I can see my new fields on both staging and Target entity
However when i import data from Data Management. Only staging contains the data and Target Fields are not getting populated

Comment: Working with AX2012 you would have needed to ["head to the Target Entity and hit Modify target mapping. Switch to the 'Mapping details' view and map the field in the Staging table to your custom Target field."](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/147569). Presumably this step will never be included in your above Project as it's applicable to the [Processing Group](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/data-importexport-framework-user-guide-dixf-dmf/) on the AX Service instance.

Comment: I did perform these steps. I also have a correct mapping from Staging to Target for new custom Fields

Answer (score 1):

If you open a list of data entities you will notice that the `Set based processing` (set based SQL operations) flag has been switched on for `LedgerJournalEntity`.

When you debug the import process you can see how method `copyCustomStagingToTarget` in `LedgerJournalEntity` performs a custom copy from staging to target.

I would suggest you to create an event handler to cater for populating the new fields in `LedgerJournalTable` and `LedgerJournalTrans`:

```
[PostHandlerFor(tableStr(LedgerJournalEntity), tableStaticMethodStr(LedgerJournalEntity, copyCustomStagingToTarget))]
```